# How to import React native navigators?

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have defined all the navigators in a navigator.js file. I want to import it. How do I do that without getting any errors? This is my navigator.js file.

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
  Platform, 
  View, 
  Button, 
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  createAppContainer,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  DrawerItems,
} from 'react-navigation';


/** NAVIGATORS DEFINED **/
const WelcomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen},
  Profile,
  Settings,
}, 
{
  tabBarOptions: {
    activeTintColor: '#fb9800',
    inactiveTintColor: '#7e7b7b',
    style: { height: 40,backgroundColor: '#fff',borderTopWidth:0.5,borderTopColor: '#7e7b7b' },
    labelStyle: {fontSize: 20}
  },
  navigationOptions:({navigation}) => {
    const {routeName} = navigation.state.routes[navigation.state.index];
    return {
      headerTitle: routeName
    };
  }

})

const WelcomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  WelcomeTabNavigator: WelcomeTabNavigator
},
{
  defaultNavigationOptions:({navigation}) => {
    return {
      headerLeft: (
        <Icon 
          style={{paddingLeft: 20}}
          onPress={() => navigation.openDrawer()}
          name="md-menu" 
          size={30}
        />
      )
    };
  }
})

const AppDrawerNavigator = createDrawerNavigator({
  Welcome: {screen: WelcomeStackNavigator},
},
{
  contentComponent:(props) => (
    <View style={{flex:1}}>
        <SafeAreaView forceInset={{ top: 'always', horizontal: 'never' }}>
            <DrawerItems {...props} />
            <Button 
              title="Logout" 
              onPress={() => {

                props.navigation.navigate('Home')
              }}
            />
        </SafeAreaView>
    </View>
  ),
  drawerOpenRoute: 'DrawerOpen',
  drawerCloseRoute: 'DrawerClose',
  drawerToggleRoute: 'DrawerToggle'
})

const AppStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: HomeScreen},
  Welcome: {screen: AppDrawerNavigator}
});

const AppContainer = createAppContainer(AppStackNavigator);
```

This is my app.js file

```
    import React, {Component} from 'react';

import {
  Platform, 
  View, 
  Button, 
  SafeAreaView,
} from 'react-native';

import {
  createAppContainer,
  createDrawerNavigator,
  createBottomTabNavigator,
  createStackNavigator,
  DrawerItems,
} from 'react-navigation';

import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/Ionicons';


import HomeScreen from './screens/HomeScreen.js';
import WelcomeScreen from './screens/WelcomeScreen.js';
import Profile from './screens/ProfileScreen.js';
import Settings from './screens/SettingsScreen.js';


class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <AppContainer />;
  }
}

export default App;
```

This is my index.js file

```
    import {AppRegistry} from 'react-native';
import App from './App';
import {name as appName} from './app.json';

AppRegistry.registerComponent(appName, () => App);
```

I want to know how to import the navigator.js file and connect these 3 files. My navigator.js file contains different navigators like tab navigator , drawer navigator, stack navigator etc. So how can I import all these in a single attempt?

Comment: first, I think you should use those navigators(all) in App.js or your main/root.js whatever you call it. and what I understand your question. What's your root file? App.js I assume. than first export the file(navigator.js) then go into App.js and import it there.

Comment: How do I do that? That navigator.js file containts different navigators right. Suppose I want to do write each navigators defined in separate files(similar ones in a single file)  and connect each other one by one how do I do that?

Comment: what you are doing not a right way to do this. first you should learn how to build a folder tree for you project. And then put the navigators stack in the App.js. App.js is your Root file. So, you should not put the screen components there, you gonna import your screen components there(welcome, home etc...)

Comment: I got it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You can combine all the navigators in one page, as long as you import all the pages.

```
import WelcomeScreen from './WelcomeScreen.js', 
import ProfileScreen from './ProfileScreen.js',
import SettingsScreen from './SettingsScreen.js',
import LogoutScreen from './LogoutScreen.js',

const WelcomeTabNavigator = createBottomTabNavigator({
  Welcome: {screen: WelcomeScreen,},
  Profile: {screen: ProfileScreen,},
  Settings: {screen: SettingsScreen,},
},

const WelcomeStackNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Home: {screen: WelcomeTabNavigator,},
  Logout: {screen: LogoutScreen,},
})

 class App extends React.Component {
        render() {
          return <WelcomeStackNavigator />;
        }
      }

export default App;
```

Comment: Sorry that was a mistake I made when I copied the code in app.js to navigator.js. But how I can combine those to files. Could you please explain it or demonstrate coz I'm a newbie to this.

Answer (score 0):

I like to tell you very simple way to update use navigation.

Below is an example of your **index.js** file

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import { StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';

    import { Main } from './navigation/Main';

    const styles = StyleSheet.create({
      container: {
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: '#fff',
      },
    });

    export class App extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <View style={ styles.container }>
            <Main />
          </View>
        );
      }
    }
```

Then here is your **Main.js** which is your navigation class. You can declare all your screen here.

```
    import {
      createStackNavigator,
      createAppContainer,
    } from 'react-navigation';

    import { FirstScreen } from '../screens/FirstScreen';
    import { SecondScreen } from '../screens/SecondScreen';

    const RootStack = createStackNavigator({
      FirstScreen: {
        screen: FirstScreen,
        key: 'FirstScreen',
        navigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
      },
      SecondScreen: {
        screen: SecondScreen,
        key: 'SecondScreen',
        navigationOptions: {
          gesturesEnabled: false,
        },
      },
    });

    export const Main = createAppContainer(RootStack);
```

Now you can simply navigate from one screen to other.

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {
  StyleSheet,
  Text,
  View,
  TouchableOpacity,
} from 'react-native';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems: 'center',
    backgroundColor: '#F5FCFF',
  },
  welcome: {
    fontSize: 20,
    textAlign: 'center',
    margin: 10,
  },
  instructions: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    color: '#333333',
    marginBottom: 5,
  },
});

class FirstScreen extends Component {
  onGetStarted() {
    const { navigate } = this.props.navigation;

    navigate('SecondScreen');
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <View style={ styles.container }>
        <TouchableOpacity
          style={ styles.welcome }
          onPress={ () => this.onGetStarted() }
        >
          <Text>
            Welcome to React Native!
          </Text>
        </TouchableOpacity>
        <Text style={ styles.instructions }>This is screen 1</Text>
      </View>
    );
  }
}

export { FirstScreen };
```

Comment: Would be better with syntax coloring! Extract from https://stackoverflow.com/editing-help : 

To manually specify the language of a fenced code block, add the language to the line with the opening fence:

``` lang-js
setTimeout(function () { alert("JavaScript"); }, 1000);
```